# Display multiple images at the same time using picasso into gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

Please help me with this.I tried this code but it diplaying the images at different times.I need to display all images at the same time.thank you for your help

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(result.thumListUrl).fetch();
                Picasso
                        .with(getContext())
                        .load(result.thumListUrl)
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .fit()
                        .into(img, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                Log.d("Picasso", "Image loaded from cache>>>" + result.thumListUrl);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                Log.d("Picasso", "Try again in ONLINE mode if load from cache is failed");
                                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(result.thumListUrl).fit().into(img, new Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
                                        Log.d("Picasso", "Image loaded from web>>>" + result.thumListUrl);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError() {
                                        Log.d("Picasso", "Failed to load image online and offline, make sure you enabled INTERNET permission for your app and the url is correct>>>>>>>" + result.thumListUrl);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `images` from `URL` and let it load when it fetches the data at different times, instead hide the `imageview` or cover it with place holder `imageview` on top of it untill all the `images` are loaded.

In Fragment

```
 private int loadedImages = 0;
    private int numberOfImagesToBeLoaded = 2;
    ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>();
    addImageUsingPicasso(url1,img1);
    addImageUsingPicasso(url2,img2);

  public void addImageUsingPicasso(String url,ImageView img){
     images.add(img);
    private Target target = new Target() {
          @Override
          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
               img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               loadedImages++;
               if(loadedImages == numberOfImagesToBeLoaded) { //<--- All images are loaded
                  showImages(); 
               }
          }

          @Override
          public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
              loadedImages++;
          }

          @Override
          public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
          }
       }
     Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(target);
   }


  private void showImages(){
     for(ImageView image : images){
         image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I only have fragment here. Do i have to create adapter ? or Can i use your code in my fragment?